# Omitting adding to an array based on if statement

Tags: php

This code creates an array and adds attribute 'payment_sum' even if `$value['CardCode'] != $prevCode` is false. You can see that I'm printing the values for testing, the last line with 509.85 summing correctly, but the array before that should have been omitted according to this `if` statement.

```
     if (($handle = fopen('upload/BEN-new.csv', "r")) === FALSE) {
            die('Error opening file'); 
         }

         $headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',');
         $cardCodes = array();
         $payments = array();
         $details = array ();

        while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ",")) {
               $cardCodes[] = array_combine($headers, $row);
        }

            $prevCode = '';

            foreach ($cardCodes as $key => $value) {

                if ($value['CardCode'] != $prevCode) {
                    $payments['payment_sum'] = $value['InvPayAmnt'];
                }
                else {
                    $payments['payment_sum'] += $value['InvPayAmnt'];
                }

                    $prevCode = $value['CardCode'];
                    print_r ($payments);
            }
            fclose($handle);
```

Printing...

```
   Array
     (
         [payment_sum] => 1055.40
     )

   Array
   (
         [payment_sum] => 550.00
   )

   Array
   (
         [payment_sum] => 100.00
    )

   Array
   (
        [payment_sum] => 287.33
   )
   Array
   (
       [payment_sum] => 509.85
   )
```

Preferred Output

```
   Array
     (
         [payment_sum] => 1055.40
     )

   Array
   (
         [payment_sum] => 550.00
   )

   Array
   (
         [payment_sum] => 100.00
    )

   Array
   (
       [payment_sum] => 509.85

         Array (
                  [currTotal] =>  287.33
                  [currTotal] =>  222.52
               )
   )
```

CSV

```
  BENV1072      1055.4
  BENV1073      550
  BENV5271      100
  BENV5635      287.33
  BENV5635      222.52
```

Comment: Why are you throwing out all the payments before `BENV5635`? For example, if you add `BENV5627 23.54` to your input file, the "total" payments will be `23.54`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I think I'm not explaining well.  Basically I am trying to group this array by the Vendor ID ie: BENxxxx and display the total amount for that group.  As you see the last 2 in the CSV should be grouped together and only display the total of 509.85

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought you would want, but that doesn't match your output.

Comment: @DavidHarkness thank you for taking the time to look at this, I modified the preferred result. That is ultimately what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time through the `for` loop you either set `$payments['payment_sum']` to the current row's payment (`$value['InvPayAmnt']`) or you add the row's payment to the total. Since the previous code is different from the current row's code for all but the final row, you're overwriting the running total over and over. Only the last row is added to the previous row's payment, giving `509.85` as the result.

You are treating `$payments` as a single-value variable rather than an array because the key under which you store the totals never changes. You need to use the vendor ID as the key.

```
$payments = array();
foreach ($cardCodes as $key => $value) {
    $payments[$value['CardCode']] += $value['InvPayAmnt'];
}
print_r($payments);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [BENV1072] => 1055.4
    [BENV1073] => 550
    [BENV5271] => 100
    [BENV5635] => 509.85
)
```

You can easily have the `$payments` array track the individual payments from the file as well as the total.

```
$payments = array();
foreach ($cardCodes as $key => $value) {
    $payments[$value['CardCode']]['payments'][] = $value['InvPayAmnt'];
    $payments[$value['CardCode']]['total'] += $value['InvPayAmnt'];
}
print_r($payments);
```

Comment: You are correct, because if there's only one payment - that is the total, if there are multiple than they need to be summed.

Comment: The above will give you one payment total per unique vendor code.

Comment: @user1413248 - When you assign a value using the array brackets, PHP will create any missing arrays or slots needed to hold it. In the second code snippet, `$payments` becomes a two-dimensional array--an array of arrays. Each subarray consists of a total mapped to the key `total` and an array containing individual payments mapped to the key `payments`. Move the `print_r` call inside the loop to see how the arrays form.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it's because both `$value['CardCode']` and `$prevCode` are either undefined or [equivalent](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). I don't see anywhere that you set `$prevCode` before you use it, even though it is in your `if` statement. At the top of your code, put `error_reporting(-1);` and you will likely be shown a notice.

Comment: Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` as well or check in your error log file.

Comment: My logic is correct here because if I do: 
if ($value['CardCode'] != $prevCode) {
   print $value['InvPayAmnt']; print '<br/>';
  }  It only omits the repeating values.  But for some reason when I do this  $payments['payment_sum'] = $value['InvPayAmnt']; it reprints both arrays.